# 3rd order moment of normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $h=[h_1\,\, h_2]'$ be a normal random vector such that
$$h\sim \mathcal{N}(h;\, 0,\, \text{diag(1/4,1/4)})$$
since $h$ is distributed symmetrically with respect its mean, is it correct to say that the 3rd order momements are zero?
$$\mathbb{E}[h_1^3]=\mathbb{E}[h_1^2 h_2]=\mathbb{E}[h_1 h_2^2]=\mathbb{E}[h_2^3]=0 ?$$

Comment: The bivariate normal with zero correlation (and centered) is a symmetric distribution. Therefore, the integrals computed in the 3rd moment will be antisymmetric and thus cancel. In conclusion, yes

Comment: $h_1$ and $h_2$ both have a normal distribution with zero mean. As $h_1$ and $h_2$ are symmetric about $0$, you have $E[h_1^3]=E[h_2^3]=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expand my comment into a full-fledged answer. We consider the first moment of 3rd order,
\begin{align}
E[h_1^3] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_1^3 c_0 \exp\left(-\frac{h_1^2}{8}\right) d h_1 \\
= -\int_0^{\infty} h_1^3 c_0 \exp\left(-\frac{h_1^2}{8}\right) d h_1 + \int_{0}^{\infty} h_1^3 c_0 \exp\left(-\frac{h_1^2}{8}\right) d h_1 \\
= 0,
\end{align}
and using similar arguments we arrive at the conclusion that
$$
E[h_2^3] = 0.
$$
Now for
$
E[h_1^2 h_2]
$ we must use the full joint distribution to compute the moment.
\begin{align}
E[h_1^2 h_2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_1^2 h_2 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} h_1 & h_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \end{pmatrix}\right) dh_1 dh_2 \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_1^2 h_2 \exp\left(-\frac{h_1^2}{8} - \frac{h_2^2}{8}\right) dh_1 dh_2 \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_1^2 h_2 \exp\left(-\frac{h_1^2}{8}\right)\exp \left( - \frac{h_2^2}{8}\right) dh_1 dh_2 \\
=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_2 \exp \left( - \frac{h_2^2}{8}\right) \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_1^2 \exp\left(-\frac{h_1^2}{8}\right) dh_1}_{=c} dh_2 \\
= c  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_2 \exp \left( - \frac{h_2^2}{8}\right) d h_2 \\
= 0
\end{align}
We do a similar operation for $E[h_2^2 h_1]$. This operation is identical to the above with $h_1, h_2$ interchanged, but yields the conclusion that
$$
E[h_2 h_1] = 0.
$$